# Datepart query shows value 1 for saturday

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is my stored procedure for setting workingday between two dates

```
Create procedure [dbo].[sp_workingdays](@startdate date,@enddate date,@createddatetime datetime,@adminid int)
as
declare @start date,@end date
declare @day varchar(50)
declare @timeid int
declare @daypare int
declare @workingdaytype varchar(20)
begin
set @start=@startdate
set @end=@enddate
while (@start<=@end)
begin
if @start not in (select  Date from Generalholyday_details)
begin
select @day= DATENAME(dw,@start)
select @workingdaytype =case (DATEPART(DW,@start)+@@DATEFIRST)%7 when 1 then 'Leave Day' when 2 then 'Full Day' when 3 then 'Full Day' when 4 then 'Full Day'when 5 then 'Full Day' when 6 then 'Full Day' when 0 then 'Half Day' end

select @timeid=Time_id from Workingdaytimesetting_details where Workingday_type=@workingdaytype
insert into Workingday_details(Working_date,working_day,Time_id) values(@start,@day,@timeid)
update Workingday_details set createddatetime=@createddatetime where createddatetime is null
update Workingday_details set adminid=@adminid where adminid is null
end
set @start=DATEADD(day,1,@start)
end
end
GO
```

In datepart line 1 is for sunday. but actually when i run the stored procedure, i got 1 for Saturday. how can i set 1 for sunday.In my previous system i got 1 for sunday in same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SET DATEFIRST (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

> Sets the first day of the week to a number from 1 through 7.
>
> To see the current setting of SET DATEFIRST, use the @@DATEFIRST
>   function.
>
> The setting of SET DATEFIRST is set at execute or run time and not at
>   parse time.
>
> Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always
>   uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is
>   deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
```

[DATEFIRST - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Also try this query after small refactor:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_workingdays] 
(
       @startdate DATE
     , @enddate DATE
     , @createddatetime DATETIME
     , @adminid INT
)
AS BEGIN

     DECLARE
            @start DATE
          , @end DATE
          , @day VARCHAR(50)
          , @timeid INT
          , @workingdaytype VARCHAR(20)

     SELECT 
            @start = @startdate
          , @end = @enddate

     WHILE (@start <= @end) BEGIN

          IF NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM Generalholyday_details
                    WHERE @start = [Date] 
          ) BEGIN

               SELECT
                      @day = DATENAME(dw, @start)
                    , @workingdaytype =
                         CASE WHEN dt = 1 THEN 'Leave Day'
                              WHEN dt IN (2,3,4,5,6) THEN 'Full Day'
                              ELSE 'Half Day'
                         END
               FROM (
                    SELECT dt = (DATEPART(DW, @start) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7
               ) t

               SELECT @timeid = Time_id
               FROM Workingdaytimesetting_details
               WHERE Workingday_type = @workingdaytype

               INSERT INTO Workingday_details (Working_date, working_day, Time_id)
               VALUES (@start, @day, @timeid)

               UPDATE Workingday_details
               SET createddatetime = @createddatetime
               WHERE createddatetime IS NULL

               UPDATE Workingday_details
               SET adminid = @adminid
               WHERE adminid IS NULL

          END
          SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @start)

     END

END
GO
```